# Alfresco One: Sending email notification to assignee on task creation

Tags: workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share, email-notifications

I am very new to Alfresco and I've been searching how to configure my Alfresco One deployment (Alfresco Enterprise Trial just downloaded from the Alfresco website), so that it sends an email to the assignee on creation of a new workflow task.

I have a clean Alfresco One installation, as I have installed it right now.

What do I have to do?

Do I need to set the SMTP configuration in order to do that?

Do I need to edit my adhoc_processdefinition.xml?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Enterprise version you can set the SMTP settings via the [Share Admin Console](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/admintools.html).
Here is the direct link to configuring [Outbound Email settings](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/adminconsole-outboundemail.html).

Be sure to check the email notification box in the workflow task.

Comment: I am trying to set SMTPS with the suggested settings

`# Sample Gmail settings
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.port=465
mail.username=user@gmail.com
mail.password=password
mail.protocol=smtps
mail.smtps.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtps.auth=true`

Comment: I have the following exception: `15:35:59,491 ERROR [org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.MailActionExecuter] Failed to send email to estoy.alfresco@gmail.com
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122099/error-in-javamail-pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification

Answer (score 0):

According to you SMTP server settings, you could also have to define an e-mail address for the user that starts the workflow.